# Mysql IDs subtraction

Tags: php, mysql

I have one MySQL query:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {...}
```

All I want to do is to subtract from the bigger ID the smaller one.
For example I have id = 500 and id = 499 and I want 500-499 = 1.

I've tried something like this:

```
$row['id'][0]-$row['id'][1]
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming the wrong structure for the array. `$row` is an array of rows, and each row is an associative array with the columns. It should be:

```
$i = $row[0]['id'] - $row[1]['id'];
```

Next time, you can use `var_dump($row)` or `print_r($row)` to see what the structure looks like and figure that out for yourself.

Comment: EDIT: Array ( [0] => 500 [id] => 500 ) Array ( [0] => 499 [id] => 499 ) And i get an error Illegal string offset 'id'